# How to get text 'shadow' effect in Silverlight Toolkit themes to work in my project

Tags: silverlight-4.0, themes

I am using the [jetpack](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/themes/jetpack.html) theme in my silverlight project. Everything is picking up the styles except I do not get the subtle text shadow effect that is visible on all the controls on the jetpack demo page.

Here is a screenshot - my project on the left, the demo site on the right.

Is there anything I have to do to enable the effect?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the label control in the toolkit.

Do this:

```
xmlns:label="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input"
```

then this

```
        <label:Label>Icon</label:Label>
```